# What is wrong with my simple g++ Makefile?

Tags: c++, makefile

I have an header file, sieve.h, that has no cpp file. Here is what I have for the makefile as of right now:

```
bitarray_executable: bitarray.o sieve.o main.o
    g++ -o bitarray.out bitarray.o sieve.o main.o

sieve.o: sieve.h
    g++ -o sieve.o -c sieve.h

main.o: main.cpp bitarray.h sieve.h
    g++ -o main.o -c main.cpp

clean:
    rm -f *.o bitarray
```

I get the error when I make it:

```
g++ -o sieve.o -c sieve.h
sieve.h:15: error: expected `)' before ‘&’ token
make: *** [sieve.o] Error 1
```

This is Sieve:

```
#ifndef _SIEVE_H
#define _SIEVE_H

#include <iostream>

#include "bitarray.h"
using namespace std;

class Sieve
{
 public:
  Sieve(BitArray& x)
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
        x.Set(i);
    }

};

#endif
```

Anyone have more experience writing makefiles to tell me what is wrong with this?

Comment: The error is in `sieve.h`, not the makefile.

Comment: Just edited sieve.h in. I'm not sure its in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.o files are compiled from files like .cpp or .c or .c++
Assuming that sieve.h is included into main.cpp since you state it has no .cpp then there is nothing to compile for it, but you can specify other dependency rules as you have done with main.o

You have no details on bitarray, so I'll assume that was a provided object file, or follows the default/implied rules for making .o

Thus your make file can be simplified to (which is almost what fazo had)

```
bitarray_executable: bitarray.o main.o
    g++ -o bitarray.out bitarray.o main.o

main.o: main.cpp bitarray.h sieve.h
    g++ -o main.o -c main.cpp

clean:
    rm -f *.o bitarray
```

To tidy up a bit further, assuming that default rule for making .o files

```
objects := $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(wildcard *.cpp))

bitarray_executable: bitarray.out

bitarray.out: $(objects)
    g++ -o bitarray.out $(objects)

main.o: main.cpp bitarray.h sieve.h

clean:
    rm -f *.o bitarray.out
```

Comment: I receive an error from that stating `makefile:2: *** missing separator.  Stop.`

Comment: Nevermind. That was due to not typing but copy and pasting. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

you are compiling header file

delete

```
sieve.o: sieve.h
    g++ -o sieve.o -c sieve.h
```

Comment: I turned it into this:

`bitarray_executable: bitarray.o sieve.o main.o
 g++ -o bitarray.out bitarray.o sieve.o main.o

main.o: main.cpp bitarray.h sieve.h
 g++ -o main.o -c main.cpp

clean:
 rm -f *.o bitarray`

But am told `make: *** No rule to make target `sieve.o', needed by `bitarray_executable'.  Stop.`